# How does MSBuild finds bindingRedirect attributes for ASP.NET projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

I have 2 machines, one runs Win10 and another - Windows Server 2012 R2. Both have Microsoft Build Tools 2015 installed. When I run `msbuild my.csproj` on Win10 machine I get 0 warnings but on Windows Server I get MSB3247 for exactly the same project:

```
[ResolveAssemblyReference] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819, 5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="protobuf-net" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="257b51d87d2e4d67" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.668" newVersion="2.0.0.668" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="RazorEngine" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="9ee697374c7e744a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.7.4.0" newVersion="3.7.4.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
```

The file Web.config contains binding redirects which seem to be applied by MSBuild on Win10 while on Windows Server this configuration file with all its  binding redirect stuff seems to be ignored. Hence, my question is: where does MSBuild look for binding redirect configuration for different types of projects and how to control this process?

Comment: What do you mean by "stuff seems to be ignored"? What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: I mean bindingRedirect stuff, like <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.668" newVersion="2.0.0.668" />.  I have added warning text to the question. That text proposes adding bindingRedirects to my Web.config file, however all redirects are already there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild step in TeamCity considers app.config instead of web.config for ASP.NET WEB API project resulting in warning MSB3247](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271216/msbuild-step-in-teamcity-considers-app-config-instead-of-web-config-for-asp-net)